# DB2 Load Failure due to timestampformat

Tags: db2, load

I'm trying to load a file into DB2 database table using DB2 Load. I'm able to load the file, using the following statement from the unix prompt.

db2 +p -x load from BOM_Sales_20130326.txt of DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL\| timestampformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss\" insert into GEO_SALES.SDM_STL_VFRSK_SALES NONRECOVERABLE

But, when I try to call DB2 Load from a script after parameterising many of the options, it does not seem to work.

For example, I have re-written the statement as follows:

db2 +p -x "load client from $FILE_DIR/$filenm of DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL\$FILE_DELMTR timestampformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS\" insert into $TGT_SCHEMA_NM.$FILE_STG_TBL_TGT NONRECOVERABLE"

All the variable are assigned with correct values prior to calling the statemant. But it seemed to fail due to wrong timestampformat. The error is as follows:

SQL3191N  The field in row "F2-1", column "1" which begins with 
"2013-03-26|STL|5678|D|3212345"
does not match the user specified DATEFORMAT, 
TIMEFORMAT, or TIMESTAMPFORMAT. The row will be rejected.

In fact, my need is to give the value "timestampformat" also as a parameter, as follows:
db2 +p -x "load client from $FILE_DIR/$filenm of DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL\$FILE_DELMTR timestampformat=$DTTIME_FMT insert into $TGT_SCHEMA_NM.$FILE_STG_TBL_TGT NONRECOVERABLE"

Since it was not working, just for the testing purpose, the variable $DTTIME_FMT was replaced with \"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS\". As said earlier, that too does not seem to work.

Request your help to fix this and also like to know whether I can parameterise the all these load options as I've tried.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: @ChrisAldrich The first paragraph says "unix prompt" if that helps.

Comment: curious as to why you have client in your script but you don't on the unix prompt?

Comment: Sure looks to me like your data doesn't match the `TIMESTAMPFORMAT` you have specified.  The rejected row looks like a date (`YYYY-MM-DD`), not a timestamp in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format

Answer (score 1):

Create your statement as follows and check your data format in your table and ensure that you match the time as well (for example, |2011-01-23 14:44:36|2011-01-23 15:44:44|20140512|
is the my time format in my DDL)

```
load from myexport.del of del modified by coldel| delprioritychar dateformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD\" timestampformat=\"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TT\"  insert into mytable
```

Good luck